# Rspec test to check user gets a self-populated ip_location attribute filled (Rails 4/devise/geocoder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, rails-geocoder

In my devise sign-up page, i have implemented an ip tracking feature that, when a user signs up, sends the country the user comes from, in order to populate the newly created account's attribute 'user_country'

**It works but as a newbie I don't know how to test with rspec that this works i.e that if i create a user who signs up, then AFTER account creation, that user_country is not empty any more.**

Here how i use a /app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb method to assign a country to the user's newly created accoun on controllers/registrations_controller.rb- see below

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  layout 'lightbox'

  def update     
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end    
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update(account_update_params) # Rails 4 .update introduced with same effect as .update_attributes
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  # for Rails 4 Strong Parameters
  def resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :user_country)
  end
  private :resource_params

  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      resource.update(user_country: set_location_by_ip_lookup.country) #use concerns/CountrySetter loaded by ApplicationController
      root_path
    end  

end
```

If it helps, this is how I find the country of a visitor:

```
module CountrySetter

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        before_filter :set_location_by_ip_lookup 
    end

    # we use geocoder gem
    # output: ip address
    def set_location_by_ip_lookup  
      if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
        Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip).first
      else
        request.location
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I see you are doing `if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?`. Be EXTREMELY careful when using literal `and` `or` in Ruby because they are meant to be used for control flow and not boolean expressions. Using them without understand their side effects may cause serious problems like having an expression always return true.

Comment: also `and` `or` have much lower order of operation than `&&` `||` http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence

Comment: thanks for these tips: i will be cautious and try to understand the difference between ANd vs && + Or vs || => as a Rails newbie i thought it was basically the same:) i'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use doubles in your test.

```
describe UserController do
  it 'sets the request location with Geocoder' do
    geocoder = class_double("Geocoder") # class double
    location = double('location', country: 'some country') # basic double with return values
    expect(geocoder).to receive(:search).and_return(location) # stubbing return value

    post :create, user_params

    user = assigns(:user)
    expect(user.user_country).to eq('some country')
  end
end
```

this way, we create a fake location and geocoder, and also create fake return values. then we assert that the return value from geocoder gets persisted as a user attribute. this way, we don't actually need to test whether `Geocoder` is working, and simplifies our test setup a lot.

the concepts used here:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/basics/test-doubles
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value

if you want to be more robust, you might be able to fake ip address in the test request context, then assert what arguments the fake geocoder is receiving with argument matching: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

in general, you should utilize mocks to isolate your tests' concerns. see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs for more documentation

Comment: thanks but when I do this in rspec/controllers Userscontroller as suggested, I get this error:
Failure/Error: post :create, user_params
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user_params' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController:0x0000000990b1f0>. Woudl you know why ? btw i use Devise for user creaiton with email/password/password confirmation (so i have controllers/RegistrationsControllers and all...)

Comment: my code is not complete. you need to populate `user_params` with whatever parameter you need to create a user. I imagine those to be at least username/email and password

Comment: hzaha ok, sorry for newbie question:). i use factory girl so i'll create a user with it